# Regex expressions and match method

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I know that match , will verify if my string match with regex expression between brakets.

```
RegExp(string.match(/\/(.+)\/.*/)[1], string.match(/\/.+\/(.*)/)[1]);
```

But what  `(/\/(.+)\/.*/)[1]` return ?

Comment: `[1]` means to return whatever was matched by the first capture group, which is `(.+)`.

Comment: lol, is that a regular expression to match for regular expressions ? very meta ..

Comment: The `\/(.+)\/.*` pattern captures in group 1 what is between the first and last occurrence of a forward slash. The `\/.+\/(.*)` pattern captures 0+times any char except a newline in group 1 after the last occurrence of a forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the following:

```
let string = "prefix /regex/ text";
```

`string.match` will return the following array:

```
[
    "/regex/ text",
    "regex"
]
```

The array has two elements:

- `[0] = "/regex/ text"` - the text that the regex matched
- `[1] = "regex"` - the text within your first group (`(.+)`)

So `string.match(/\/(.+)\/.*/)[1]` returns `"regex"` in this example

Note that this regex is a bit naive. Given the following input:

```
"/regex1/ some text /regex2/"
```

`string.match(/\/(.+)\/.*/)[1]` will end up returning:

```
"regex1/ some text /regex2"
```

which probably wasn't intended. But I don't know when/how this code is used, so maybe it's safe to assume that the input will contain only one regex.